# Promote the vi/vim SE page on all StackOverflow questions tagged vi/vim?

Tags: discussion

Wouldn't it be a good idea to show a banner/link/whatever to the new, beta vi/vim Stack Exchange site whenever the user is looking at a Stack Overflow questions tagged with (or perhaps simply containing the words) vi or vim?  I can't see how it would be annoying; it's a new site and therefore people who've always posted about vi/vim there won't necessarily be aware of it.

I'm not suggesting the wording should give people get a lecture about how SO is the wrong place for vi/vim questions, either now or when the new site is up - just raise awareness that it exists so that it has a change to escape beta status.

This approach could be used on other beta sites as a matter of course.  And the banner/link would only need to appear for a long as the site is in beta, to help promote it into a full member of SE.

Comment: Why not put it in the tag description? Is there any precedent for that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That wouldn't help people reading the many, many existing questions though, right?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so.

One effect of having this information would make people think that such questions should be migrated to the vi/vim site when they are **perfectly on topic on Stack Overflow**. This would lead to more comments along the lines of:

> this would be better asked on the vi/vim site

which are just noise and lead to cross posting.

What would be worse is that this notice would appear on old (> 60 day old) questions leading people to erroneously request migration of these questions too - a request we are unable to fulfil.

All in all this would lead to more confusion, noise and work for the moderators.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I don't suppose you'd be happy that any particular wording would solve this problem?  Or just forgetting the banner idea and just having a link with the text "beta vi/vim site" in/near the Related section so that observant/curious people are aware the beta site exists?  I'm only suggesting this exist for as long as the site is in beta; this shouldn't produce an epic amount of work forever!

Comment: @Alex I don't think any wording would be suitable.