# Questions about Vim on Stack Overflow and migration to Vi & Vim

Tags: discussion, migration

I wonder if we could consider actions that would encourage questions about Vim to be asked on [Vi & Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com) or migrated there from Stack Overflow.

This has been [asked in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306735/9447571), but I wonder if the opinions towards this changed in the last 5 years, particularly since the Vi & Vim site is a lot more active now.

Pros:

- For those **asking** questions: they're likely to reach more people who can answer their questions in a more specialized community.
- For those of us **answering**: we won't need to keep closely monitoring both the Vi & Vim *and* [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) on Stack Overflow for questions to answer.
- For the **Vi & Vim** site: right now the volume of questions asked on Stack Overflow tagged [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) is quite similar to that of the Vi & Vim site. So, concentrating all the questions on Vi & Vim would potentially double the activity on Vi & Vim, fostering a more active community and possibly helping that site graduate from Beta.
- For the **Vi & Vim** site: it would be easier to mark questions as duplicates. Right now we often find duplicates but on the other site and we can't mark them as such.
- For **Stack Overflow**: less noise for those who come to the site with questions about coding. Also there will be a smaller burden in migrating questions there manually through moderator intervention.

Cons:

- ???
- Perhaps some users might feel more at home on Stack Overflow (because they've been using it forever) and would be reticent to join a separate stack to ask their questions.

Anecdotally, I can mention that I often post a comment encouraging users who asked questions on Vim on Stack Overflow to consider posting their next questions on Vi & Vim instead. I've seen other active members of the Vi & Vim community do the same.

I have also suggested migrating questions through moderator intervention and have had them migrated quite a few times. (The two I had migrated this week don't seem to have had any constraints regarding Vim also being on topic on Stack Overflow.)

The Superuser Stack Exchange site is one where some questions about Vim sometimes land, they have been very proactive in having those migrated to Vi & Vim. Unix & Linux also gets them sometimes, although their volume is much lower than on Stack Overflow.

So I thought it would be worth starting a discussion to see whether the status quo stands or whether there's interest in considering a course of action that might mutually benefit both communities.

Comment: Vi and Vim are on topic here, so why migrate them in the first place?

Comment: @10Rep Why duplicate efforts?

Comment: The question you mentioned as *previous*  asks about *promoting* that site via banner shown when looking at questions with vi tags/words. What's your idea? Taking as example [SO vs codereview vs ..](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102852/299295) it is always a problem if user is not aware about *correct* site. It's a bigger problem and not localized to vi as you can see.

Comment: @10Rep Vi and Vim are both text editors (be it quite advanced) don't see how that makes them "on-topic" for [so].

Comment: @Lankymart, questions relevant to programming are on-topic, see [tag:vi] tag.

Comment: @Sinatr you mean questions about programming [tag:vi] are on-topic, so [tag:C] or [tag:gcc] then? :/

Comment: @Lankymart, I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @Sinatr (You don't need to it's rhetorical) I'm saying that [tag:vi] isn't a programming language, so if a [tag:vi] question is "on-topic" it would need to be about programming [tag:vi] not just set some variables to change functionality etc. However, if your "programming" [tag:vi] chances are that's using [tag:c] or [tag:gcc]. Just looking at the [tag:vi] question queue it's clear why this question is being asked.

Comment: Another Con: The migrated questions will be lost, if the beta fails.

Comment: @Lankymart, see what's [related to programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12373/299295) means, there are many on-topic possibilities, [tag:c] and [tag:gcc] are just some. It doesn't matter if tag is not a programming language itself. E.g. [tag:notepad] tag: can be on-topic and [off-topic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notepad). If question is on-topic on SO **it shouldn't be migrated**.

Comment: @Thomas doesn't the question stay on Stack Overflow, but with a banner that it has been migrated? Though the new answers are not mirrored

Comment: @Sinatr nothing you linked there is that conclusive and a lot of hearsay and conjecture. Just viewing the [tag:vi] question queue it's clear a lot of them are not "programming" questions.

Comment: @Lankymart, it could be many of them are offtopics. But those what aren't should stay on SO. Btw, there is also [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vi), what to do with those?

Comment: @Sinatr OP covered this - *"The Superuser Stack Exchange site is one where some questions about Vim sometimes land, they have been very proactive in having those migrated to Vi & Vim. Unix & Linux also gets them sometimes, although their volume is much lower than on Stack Overflow."*.

Comment: @Lankymart, right. I don't have time right now to go through [tag:vi] and sort out which of them are on-topic, but I bet you will find *many* (that's the point of my comments). Since you have doubts, maybe you will do it?

Comment: @Sinatr I'm simply suggesting that the question has some merit based on my brief look at the [tag:vi] question queue. Not suggesting people start going through the queue and closing questions or anything, just showing my support for the question.

Comment: I think it would help to clarify the original reason why some editors (vi/vim and emacs) get their own Stack Exchange, while for others (Eclipse, VS Code, Visual Studio) tagging is sufficient. Once that is clear, the benefits of migration might be more obvious. (Not arguing for or against.)

Comment: @Lankymart I don't think you have to be programming vi for it to be on topic, just like you don't have to be writing extensions to Visual Studio for questions about it to be on topic. "Software tools commonly used by programmers" are explicitly on-topic for SO, which would certainly include editors and IDEs.

Comment: Another con: if we decide that Vim questions are suddenly off-topic here, actually enforcing that new policy will take [a lot of effort](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/unicode_2x.png).

Comment: @reirab The Stack Overflow Help was changed [in or before 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130810/146632) to state that questions about software tools commonly used by programmers are on topic only if they are _also_ [unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Simply being about vi/Vim is no longer considered sufficient.

Comment: ...although I should probably note that the accepted and top-voted answer on the meta.se question I linked to above states that the answerer considers _all_ questions about vi/Vim to be on-topic on SO, so it's possible there's some divergence between the official position and the community feeling there. (Just for the record, I'd personally much prefer all future vi questions to be on vi.se.)

Comment: I'm disappointed the site was named "Vi & Vim" instead of "Vim & Vi," which rolls off the tongue so much better and also has built-in pun potential for "Vim & Vi-gor" or some such nonsense.

Comment: @Rich Yes, it does say that the question must be unique to software development, so that might theoretically remove some vi/vim questions from, say, sysadmins, but, realistically, most Vim usage is for programming anyway, so that's probably not going to limit what's on-topic here much. An SU mod also commented on that same meta post saying that all Vim questions were also considered on-topic at SU.

Comment: @Voo Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: 9000 questions about Vi & Vim - that product does not seem to be self-explanatory.

Comment: Migrating new questions is Ok, but not old ones

Comment: @ThomasWeller only because so few read `:help` which is quite literally explains itself :)

Comment: Points 1-3 kindof assume that SO askers & answerers are or would-be as active on Vi & Vim. If an answerer of SO content including Vim posts now would need to now check 2 sites, that seems less convenient to me.

Comment: This just shows the inadequacies of the Stack Exchange network model. Why would anyone use that `Vi & Vim` beta site when there are orders of magnitude more potential answers on SO and SuperUser? Now if there were a single site where you could tag `Vi` or `Vim` and *"cross post"* to everyone on Stack Exchange...

Comment: Generally speaking, you will get better answers at the vi site @pkamb, the site is broader in scope, and also has a much friendlier community IMO.

Comment: Amount of questions tagged `vi` or `vim` on various sites: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/611134/vi-questions-across-stack-exchange-per-month-with-graph#graph – jut FYI.

Comment: @MartinTournoij looks like since ~2019, we get the most vi-related questions...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to encourage people to use VI.SE, feel free to. I have a canned comment for people misusing the SEO tag to ask their SEO questions on Webmasters.SE. There's no harm in telling people about more specific SE sites in comments.

Migration is trickier because technically migration is really a closure. That means the question needs to be off-topic on SO first. We decided long ago that SEO (which is really website marketing) [wasn't a programming topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281371/2370483) which makes that easy. But vi and vim are considered *programming tools* for most applications. If you want to start another Meta question about where we can draw that line, feel free, but understand that

1. Mods are leery of migration anyways (we don't know what other sites' topic policies are in most cases)
2. We err on the side of programming tools being on-topic on SO, and that policy tends to be broad

Without some pretty clear *community supported* guidelines, I don't see this policy changing.

Comment: Not only they are programming tools, but vim has it's own scripting language, with support for pluggins. Asking questions about debugging .vim code should be on topic, as long as they follow the guidelines.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity (just because I can't think of any immediately,) other than the vim and emacs stacks, are there other stacks where _nearly their entire scope_ is on-topic for SO? That does seem like it creates a kind of weird situation.

Comment: @reirab I'm not sure of all the Stacks out there, but Programmers/Software Engineering has a ton of overlap. I'm sure there's some esoteric ones that do as well.

Comment: @reirab code review, code golf, software engineering, tex and latex, wordpress development, etc. Despite the scope being defined "broadly" actually is very focused into _practical_ questions _unique_ to software development

Comment: Speaking as someone who would prefer to have all the vi questions in one place (on the specialised vi.se site), this answer is frustrating. Nothing in it is _wrong_, but it doesn't address the main point of the question, which is that there are lots of reasons why vi questions would be better on the dedicated vi.se site, and very few downsides to shifting them there. You haven't made any counterarguments to this point: you've just restated what the status quo is.

Comment: @Rich: It is possible and quite normal that a question is on-topic on multiple sites. The kinds of answers that the question gets will however typically be different, so the asker can choose the community based on which types of answers they want. If people prefer the kinds of answers they are getting on Vi & Vim, they will be posting their questions there anyway, and if they prefer the kinds of answers they are getting on SO, then who are we to deny them that choice?

Comment: @Rich Quite the opposite. Again, to migrate from SO, it first needs to be off-topic on SO, and we've established that generally isn't the case. If you want to cross this bridge we first need a good source (like a Meta question) that clearly delineates what vi/vim questions are off-topic for SO. Most people, if given a choice, would prefer to ask on SO since it gets more traffic. We can't babysit the vi/vim tags to push them all to VI.SE either.

Comment: @Machavity filbranden will correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that discussion is what this question was intended to initiate.

Comment: @Rich No, this question is about [migration]. What you need is a discussion about [scope]

Comment: It's not really the case that the entire scope of the Vi site is on-topic on SO @reirab; quite a few questions on the Vi site would be closed on SO. If you read the [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) the last two items are an AND (not OR): "software tools AND problem that is unique to software development'. There's certainly plenty of overlap, but generally speaking the Vi site is much more broad.

Comment: interesting... this is the mod answer I expected, but it seems to conflict with the voting on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287108/11107541, which dictates a much narrower definition of what vi/vim questions are within scope for SO, and recommends migrating questions that are not within that definition. also interesting is the answer voting on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375552/11107541.

Comment: another mod answer I expected, which lines up with this one is under: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306735/11107541